# Dynamically generated SELECT with with jQuery needs double click to open in IE8

Tags: jquery, html, cross-browser

All the dynamically generated select boxes have this issue, if i click once, it flashes, if I hold click it opens and you can navigate the list, but CAN'T make any selection, and ONLY if I double click you can see the list and actually select an element.

The option's inside the select are hooked to go to another page when clicked, but I generated two simple unhooked selects in a different area of the site and the result is the same.

Any ideas?

```
jQ('.slider-brands span.small-txt').addClass('cselect').append('<select><option>Choisir une marque</option></select>')
            //Populate the select with all the brands from the list
            for (var i = 0; i < brandsName.length; i++) {
                jQ('.slider-brands .cselect select').append('<option value="' + brandsLink[i] + '">' + brandsName[i] + '</option>')
            }
            //Go to location on click
            jQ('.slider-brands .cselect select').bind('change', function () {
                var url = jQ(this).val(); // get selected value
                if (url) { // require a URL
                    window.location = url; // redirect
                }
                return false;
            });
```

And this outputs this

```
<select>
  <option>Choisir une marque</option>
  <option value="/alsa">Alsa</option>
  <option value="/axe">Axe</option>
  <option value="/belin">Belin</option>
  <option value="/belvita-petit-dejeuner">belVita Petit Déjeuner</option>
</select>
```

Comment: The idea is that I WANT SINGLE click, not double click like the other question here on stackoverflow :)

Comment: This is sounding like more than one jQuery version added to the same page.

Comment: and the version of jquery and IE8 you are using. Best thing would be a jsfiddle.

Comment: The issues is not HOW it's generated, I'm generating two selects, one more complex, this, and another simple one, the behavior is the same, the code is the same, WORKS EVERYWHERE ELSE.

Comment: And arrogance is not welcomed here. If you didn't want people to ask you bits to make it possible to help you, just don't come here and ask for help.

Comment: OK, i'll prepare this and post the fiddle link. Thanks!

Comment: Wasn't arrogant, the issue is I have 5000lines of JS, the code is irrelevant after the select is generated. it should open no matter what IF there's no extra handlers on it.  Sorry for the misunderstanding guys :).

Comment: Do you have a click event? without a click event clicking on the select should simply cause it to gain focus, unless you change the value nothing should happen other than default functionality. there's obviously more to this than what you have shown us.

Comment: Yes, the only event that I know of is this `jQ('.slider-brands .cselect select').bind('change', function () {...`

Comment: I've seen this kind of issue happening for two reasons: More than one version of jQuery added to the page; Two document ready handlers on the same page. If it's none of these situations, I'm here to see what's wrong then.

Comment: Yes, it is a Drupal 6 .. a HUGE clusterf*** ... we have 1.3.2 and 1.8.3 running on different namespaces :). jQ is for 1.8.3, $ & jQuery is for 1.3.2. I ironed out most of the issues on IE regarding the JS issues but this select issue is  annoying

Comment: Look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zbJnY/ it's using every bit of the code and html you have provided, plus some you haven't, however it doesn't replicate the issue. Therefore, you have not provided enough information to solve this problem. **come back when you've reduced your problem down to a reproducible test-case.**

Comment: One option is then dismissed, as you're working out the conflicts.

Comment: I keep writting here, rather than replicating the issue in a fiddle, I'll try, the site is HUGE, not sure I can simulate everything what's there. I'll have to test. Also, this is the IE8 version I have http://screencast.com/t/7JgAiDxJUFZ

Comment: We don't want you to replicate the entire site. We're only interested in the issue you are having. It's obviously related to something you haven't given us yet. Two different versions of jQuery shouldn't have anything to do with this.

Comment: I know I don't need to replicate the entire site :)). To replicate as much of what's on that page until I see it happen in jsfiddle. There's  a communication gap here, sorry, I might be overworked.

Comment: @MelanciaUK I would also bet on some hacking script trying to apply a fixed width on the selects in IE8 and lower. Calling unbind for events "click", "mousenter" on the selects might be a good starting point. monitoring live/on and calling the corresponding die/off might be another.

Comment: Yeah ... this is how jsFiddle.net looks on my IE8 ... http://screencast.com/t/xQdYNsdZIWdd .. Not sure how you guys tested, or I have some flaw here.

Comment: Apparently the behavior just, I restarted my VM for some other reason and now IT WORKS (without any actual code changes.), I'm flabbergasted ... and I cleared the CACHE A LOT DURING these 3 hrs. I still want to get to the bottom of this but can't reproduce it anymore :(. IE works in mysterious ways.